# How to implement gpg encryption in git bash

Tags: bash, gnupg

I am trying to implement gpg encryption both in a shell script and at the prompt in git bash, but I get the following error:

> usage: gpg [options] --encrypt [filename]

The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

$1="cd C:\Users\XXXX\Documents"

dir $1

gpg --encrypt --output *.csv.gpg  --recipient username *.csv
```

The logic in the above code is to search for all the csv files in the particular directory and encrypt the files thereby renaming them to filename.csv.gpg using gpg keys. I am not able to find any specific solution to this.

I tried searching for the specific syntax but couldn't find any exact command for the error which is throwing. I tried some permutation and combination but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: You need to write the statements into different lines, not all of them in one line.

Comment: I had written in different lines originally but somehow they appeared in same line after submission.Now they are in different lines.

Comment: Not a `git` question

Comment: Please read here how to [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `$1="cd C:\Users\XXXX\Documents"` does not make sense and should produce an error message. In addition, it would make sense that you show how you invoke your script.

Comment: I execute the script using the command: bash file_encryption.sh.

Answer (score 1):

> gpg --encrypt --output *.csv.gpg --recipient username *.csv
>
> The logic in the above code is to search for all the csv files in the particular directory and encrypt the files …

Obviously `gpg` does not work with wildcards and multiple files, so you need a loop.

```
for file in *.csv
do  gpg --encrypt --output "$file.gpg" --recipient username "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But when i execute the code,it gives error now as No public key.There is one key which i had generated earlier and its not expired either.

Comment: That is a different issue and does not belong to the question here.